# Decoding a uuencoded file

Tags: decoding

There is a data set freely available here: http://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/hydro/GRAV/GRAV2D/index.html in the last line under the word "here". Unfortunately it is `uuencoded`, and I am unable to decode it.

Can somebody help me with it or at least point me in the right direction. How do I go about decoding a uuencoded (.uu) file?

Direct link: http://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/hydro/GRAV/GRAV2D/A_E2_20.uu

Edit:
Well... after I did everything suggested below I got bunch of files of "file" type whose content viewed in Notepad looks like this:
&_

which to me looks still unreadable. Any suggestions?

Comment: WinZip 12 seems to be able to open both the .uu file as well as the subsequent (,z and .tar) archives underneath. Not my preferred archiver by any stretch but it does everything needed here.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: If you have any questions about the uudecode process or extracting process, but if zip files are easier, I've posted [this zip file at a temporary URL](http://bespin.org/~toogmedu/temp/tempfile.zip) so you can compare your results.  Making sense of the data is something I leave up to you to accomplish (without my current plans for further assistance)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do it - under Linux the easiest way to do it is to simply type "uudecode filename".

There are also lots of online decoders - just type "online uudecoder" into Google.  Similarly, a search for windows uudecoder yields a number of pieces of software that will do this.

Note that for the file you linked, the resulting file is a tar.Z file, which will need to be decompressed.   This is trivial under Linux (tar -xzf filename), and I'd expect that a decent decompression program for Windows will handle this as well as it is a "gzip" file - quite a common format.